# sending data from java to JasperReports sub dataset

Tags: java, dataset, jasper-reports

I'm trying to use Java to call many reports made in jasper, I can call the jasper and give data to the main dataset but when I need to make some diferent datasets to have diferent tables in the report, I don't know how it's posible send data to there.
Its posible give data to these datasets? and if its posible. Why can I give data to subdatasets of jasper using java?

Comment: you can send parameter values to the sub report. It's not what you want to do? What kind of data do you want to send?

Comment: I want send the collection of values to the dataset. like the JRBeanCollectionDataSource that I can send to the main dataset using the fillReport Metod from JasperFillManager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send data from the main report to the dataset/subreport, data which you already have sent to the main report as a datasource, why don't you send this via the connection expression of the dataset/subreport using the `REPORT_DATA_SOURCE` main report parameter?

Comment: I focus my efforts trying to send a Colection (a vector) directly to the dataset using java. I didn't think it was possible to send it as a parameter and pass from the report to a subdataset, in fact don't know how I can do, but now you've given me the idea and I will try to find a way to do it.